# Spring Security Role based on Okta Group

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, okta, okta-api

Hello I would like to assign Spring Security rules based on and named after Okta groups.
Let's assume my groups are called Foo and Bar.

I have set up the okta app to claim the groups.

```
groups  groups: matches regex .*    Any access  Always
```

My POM looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>CLASSIFIED</groupId>
<artifactId>CLASSIFIED</artifactId>
<version>CLASSIFIED</version>
<name>CLASSIFIED</name>
<description>CLASSIFIED</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Application.Properties looks like this:

```
okta.oauth2.redirect-uri=/authorization-code/callback
okta.oauth2.postLogoutRedirectUri=http://localhost:8080/
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://CLASSIFIEDURL/oauth2/default
okta.oauth2.client-id=CLASSIFIED
okta.oauth2.client-secret=CLASSIFIED
rolesClaim=groups
```

My Security Configuration looks like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
     getHttp().authorizeRequests()
     // Require authentication for all requests 
     
     .anyRequest().authenticated()
     
     // enable OAuth2/OIDC
     .and()
         .oauth2Login();
```

And the Servers for the restricted pages look like this:

```
  @GetMapping("/classified")
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_FOO')")
  public String classified(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user,Model model) {
    some unimportant logic
    return "classified";
}

  @GetMapping("/42")
  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_BAR')")
   public String fortytwo(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user,Model model) {
    some unimportant logic
    return "fortytwo";
}
```

The Roles FOO and BAR are not given to the user, so they are not able to access the restricted pages.

Also the non restricted page shows this message:
you are a [ROLE_USER, SCOPE_address, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_offline_access, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_phone, SCOPE_profile]!

So it is quite sure that the problem is, that the user does not receive the role from Okta.
(The Text in[ ] brackets is the result of user.getAuthorities().)

Now I'm wondering if any important classes are missing or if I did an error when configuring.

Comment: The login by itself works fine by the way, just the role assignment does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `groups` claim to the ID token, it should work.

[image: Add groups claim to ID token]

Also, your `rolesClaim=groups` is incorrect. The key should be named `okta.oauth2.groupsClaim` (according to https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot). However, since `groups` is the default, you can just delete it.

Comment: @zonk can you please share me your github repo for this project. I am facing the exact issue.